# What join to use in this case?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have our yearly sales thus far for 2017 in the query marked as `Yearly` and our all time Inventory marked as `AllTime`. I need an advice on what join I could use or what additional code I could add to my already script which would get me to show the value marked as (null) in the result. The (null) values represents `Robin` from the `Yearly` table but since I do not have that value in the `AllTime` query it is displayed as `null` in the result. If I change the order of the resultant query to `from yearly left outer join alltime`, `Red Arrow` and `Captain Marvel` both lose their respected spots since both have zero values in the `Yearly` query. If I change to `from alltime left outer join yearly`, the null value (Robin) goes away. Please share your advice. And as always, if you require additional details, let me know please.

```
with AllTime as 

(select dp.Builder,
count(*) "My Inventory" from alldatainput dp
where Project_ID = 'GAP'
group by rollup ((dp.Builder))           

),

Yearly as 

(                   

select Builder,(count
(Sale_Date) filter (where extract(year from Sale_Date) = 2017 
and Project_ID = 'GAP'))
 - (count(Cancelled) filter (where extract(year from Cancelled) = 2017 
and Project_ID = 'GAP')) as "Net for 2017"
from allsalesdata sd
and Project_ID = 'GAP'
group by rollup((Builder))
having (count(Sale_Date) filter (where extract(year from Sale_Date) = 2017 
and Project_ID = 'GAP' ))
- (count(Cancelled) filter (where extract(year from Cancelled)   = 2017 and 
sd.Project_ID = 'GAP')) > 0
)

select alltime.Builder,coalesce(yearly."Net for 2017",0) 
as "YTD Home Sales", coalesce(alltime."My Inventory",0) as "My Inventory"
from allTime
full join yearly on allTime.Builder = yearly.Builder 
group by rollup((allTime.Builder,yearly."Net for 2017",alltime."My Inventory",
yearly.Builder))
order by yearly.Builder;
```

Result:

```
  Builder           YTD Home Sales    My Inventory
  Batman                  3             86
  Superman                5             26
  Aquaman                 3             29
  Martian                 6             84
  Green Lantern           2             21
  Wonder Woman            1              3
  Flash                   2             74
  ****(null)              4              0   ************
  Cyborg                  2             54
  Batwing                 5             25
  Captain Marvel          0             15
  Red Arrow               0              1
                          33            0
                          0             418
```

Comment: It might be easiest if instead of the cte's you showed the data each one produces. Always easier to go from data than queries, imo.

Comment: You need to use the table for all builders and then left join yearly to all builders and then left join all times to all builders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Builder, sum(x."YTD Home Sales") as "YTD Home Sales",
sum(x."My Inventory") as "My Inventory"
from (
select Builder, yearly."Net for 2017" as "YTD Home Sales",
0 as "My Inventory"
from yearly
UNION
select Builder, 0 as "YTD Home Sales",
alltime."My Inventory"
from alltime
) x 
group by Builder
order by Builder;
```